# Blazor, Selectable Checkbox inside Selectable table row

Tags: blazor

I have this tr and its two tds:

```
 <tr class="@rowClasses[index]" @onclick="@((e) => RowClicked(index, outageItems.EventID))">
    <td class="col-checkbox chkColumn quarter">
       <input type="checkbox" name="@index" value="@outageItems.EventID"
              @onchange="eventArgs => { CheckboxClicked(outageItems.EventID, eventArgs.Value); }" />
    </td>
    <td class="col-Row quarter">...</td>
    <td>...</td> ...
```

The checkboxes and row clicks should both select the row (with the checkbox more than one row can be selected), But a collision occures and row click always wins.
A event:stopPropagation="true" does not help since row click is higher in the hierarchy.
How to select work with both events?

Comment: can you try like this on your checkbox `<input type="checkbox" onclick="event.stopPropagation();"/>`

Comment: What exactly is the conflict?  How do you store 'Selected' ?

Comment: Having an overlying Row click event on top of a cell click event is shooting yourself in the foot, as you've discovered.  What does `RowClicked` and `Checkbox` clicked do?  If you want to do something that all the other columns in the row do but not the one where you have the checkbox, add a cell based click event to each cell.

Comment: What do you mean "row click always wins"?  Doesn't the checkbox also get triggered?

Comment: put @onclick="@((e) => RowClicked(index, outageItems.EventID))" on the other <td> elements individually, and remove it from <tr> tag

Comment: By mistake I used onchange:stopPropagation="true" in input tag but the correct way is: onclick:stopPropagation="true" that solved my problem.